# Sync MySQL table with different table name

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two Django application on 2 servers. (application "A" & application "B")
I want to synchronize one table(table's name is "member") from A to B.

Since I'm using Django and the actual table name is "a_member" and "b_member", I cannot use MySQL replication or pt-table-sync. (caused by different table name)

What is the best way to synchronize(one-way) these two tables?
using python script, django, mysql or other tools?

Thanks!

Comment: are the records same in both the tables

Comment: This is not a promming but a database administration question. There are sibling sites if SO which are better suited for this topic.

Comment: Actually, it will update and create data in application A to that table. Then I want to copy it to application B(e.g. every 5 mins), and application B only read this table. So only one-way sync is needed.

Comment: Hi Klaus, I'm not sure if python script can do it or not, since mysql replication and pt-table-sync didn't work for this case.